# Javascript error happening only in IE, how do I track it down? (link to site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mootools

I am using Lemonstand (an e-commerce CMS) and after going live with our site we started hearing that IE wasn't working as expected.

I can't track down what's going on.

The website is at http://store.kramerknives.com, the problem is when you go through checkout in IE - any of the Ajax functions throw a Syntax error (it says line 8, which is a Meta Description tag, rather unhelpful), as well as an 'error 80020101'.

This causes it:

- clicking 'My billing and shipping addresses are the same'
- navigating backwards on the breadcrumb

Is this problem too specific for Stack Overflow? I am at a loss, I have been tweaking things around but I'm unfamiliar with Developer Tools in IE to fully grok what's breaking what.

Comment: It probably means `Line 8` of a script file included on your page.  If you can post that line, or the lines around it, people might be able to help more.  BTW, IE is often picky about a comma after the last item in an array.

Comment: I couldn't find any offending commas - the site doesn't have any errors until a button or link is pressed, which have code like this:   
 
onclick="return $(this).getForm().sendRequest('on_action', {update:{'checkout_page': 'checkout_partial'}})"

Comment: I'd check it out under a debugger for you, but unfortunately your site is blocked by our firewall here because it pertains to weapons..  Go figure..

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method checkout line 157"

Comment: @MikeChristensen is right about the offending comma. That's how I'm getting the 80020101 error tonight and it was very frustrating to chase this down -- spent literally hours in the IE debugger chasing stupid stuff. No other browser complains but IE. I was making an AJAX call on a button click, and the last item in the array had a comma after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running under the IE9 debugger in IE9 mode, I see an error here on the execScript() line which is getting called after an ajax call when going to the next step in the cart:

```
if (window.execScript){
    window.execScript(text);
} else {
```

Which basically means a bunch of your initialization javascript code after an ajax call doesn't get executed and thus the page doesn't work properly.

Comment: I saw this before, but couldn't figure out what it meant. I realized it was in a js_combine function (built into Lemonstand, not my code), which combined and minified the .js files. I replaced this and hand-wrote the includes for the javascript files and it seems to have fixed this. The checkout works now in IE, it's just throwing syntax errors still! But they're coming from the jQuery source code?

Comment: look at the source code it generates on ajax requests, ridiculous. broken markup, bad js, reliance on jquery ready and mootools windows events, inline event handlers... this is not how you structure an app--reliance on logic to come though the request is a bad idea - esp for e-commerce. the ajax should just return data, used in display - think, JSON - objects.

Comment: I thought it was quite strange the way they did it.